# Not able to load any Raster File using QGIS Python

Tags: qgis, raster, pyqgis

I am trying to run an elementary piece of Python code, that simply loads a dem file as a raster accessing the QGIS Python API.

On the embedded console (within the QGIS application GUI), it runs fine and the raster loads. However, it does not load work when I run it outside of the embedded console, from a standard windows prompt AFTER setting up QGIS_PREFIX_HOME and PYTHONPATH using a batch file.

The code I am running is as follows:

```
import os

from PyQt4.QtCore import QFileInfo, QSettings
from qgis.core import *

# load providers
QgsApplication.initQgis()

# Load an input dem
rasterFile = "E:\\data\\43j11\\43J11.dt2"
fileInfo = QFileInfo(rasterFile)    
fileName=fileInfo.fileName()
baseName = fileInfo.baseName()
print "Loading raster layer:" + fileName

if fileInfo.exists():
    print "Raster file specified exists."
else:
    print "File does not exist"
    exit(1)

errorStr = "Unknown"
if QgsRasterLayer.isValidRasterFileName(rasterFile, errorStr):
    print "File is a valid raster"
    rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(rasterFile, baseName)
    if not rlayer.isValid():
        print "Layer failed to load!"
    else:
        print "Successfully loaded dem: " + fileName    
else:
    print "File is not a valid raster. Error: " + errorStr  

QgsApplication.exitQgis()
```

Within the embedded console, the output I get is:

```
Loading raster layer:43J11.dt2
Raster file specified exists.
File is a valid raster
Successfully loaded dem: 43J11.dt2
```

Outside the embedded console, the output I get is:

```
Loading raster layer:43J11.dt2
Raster file specified exists.
File is not a valid raster. Error: Unknown
```

I suspect this is a path/initialization problem, so I am also including the .bat file I am using here:

```
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=C:\Program Files\QGIS Wien
set PYTHONHOME=%QGIS_PREFIX_PATH%\apps\Python27
set PYTHONPATH=%QGIS_PREFIX_PATH%;^
%QGIS_PREFIX_PATH%\lib;^
%QGIS_PREFIX_PATH%\bin;^
%QGIS_PREFIX_PATH%\apps\qgis\python\plugins;^
%QGIS_PREFIX_PATH%\apps\Python27;^
%QGIS_PREFIX_PATH%\apps\Python27\Lib;^
%QGIS_PREFIX_PATH%\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages;^
%QGIS_PREFIX_PATH%\apps\qgis\python;^
%QGIS_PREFIX_PATH%\apps\Python27\DLLs;^
%QGIS_PREFIX_PATH%\apps\qgis\bin;^
%QGIS_PREFIX_PATH%\apps\qgis\plugins;^
%QGIS_PREFIX_PATH%\bin\gdalplugins;^
%QGIS_PREFIX_PATH%\apps\saga\modules;^
%QGIS_PREFIX_PATH%\apps\Qt4\plugins;^
%QGIS_PREFIX_PATH%\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\lib;^
%QGIS_PREFIX_PATH%\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\bin
set PATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%PATH%
```

I need it to work outside of the embedded console since I need to package QGis as part of my application. My eventual plan is to include a .bat file where I will set the QGIS_PREFIX_HOME from my application's installer.

Comment: @gcarrillo That did the trick. Can you please convert your comment to an answer so that I can accept it as one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to include this line:

```
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:\\Program Files\\QGIS Wien\\apps\\qgis", True)
```

right before this one:

```
QgsApplication.initQgis()
```